# "The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID" with attemptInvisibleVerification

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I had a working auth with reCaptcha verification on Firebase, sadly as soon as I try to implement attemptInvisibleVerification I get an error, and I'm unable to log in. I've kinda tried everything and I couldn't find any working fix, I would appreciate your help!

The error I get is :

```
Firebase: The phone auth credential was created with an empty verification ID. (auth/missing-verification-id).
at http://192.168.0.37:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:128521:321 in _createSuperInternal
at http://192.168.0.37:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:129135:26 in FirebaseError
at http://192.168.0.37:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:129169:37 in create
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/internal.js:308:0 in _getAndRemoveEvent
at node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/esm2017/internal.js:287:4 in CordovaAuthEventManager#initialized
at http://192.168.0.37:19000/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:136372:17 in _performFetchWithErrorHandling$
```

Here is my code:

```
const auth = getAuth()
const [phone, setPhone] = useState(route.params.phone)
const [code, setCode] = useState('')
const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState()
const recaptchaVerifier = useRef(null)
const attemptInvisibleVerification = true;

const confirmCode = async () => {

        try {
            const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
              verificationId,
              code
            );
            await signInWithCredential(auth, credential);
            Alert.alert('Phone authentication successful ')
        } catch (err) {
            Alert.alert(`Error: ${err.message}`)
        }
}

const sendCode = async () => {
        try {
            const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth)
            const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phone, recaptchaVerifier.current)
                .then(() => {
                    console.log('working')
                    setVerificationId(verificationId)
                })   
        } catch (error) {
            Alert.alert(error.message)
        }
    }

useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setPhone(route.params.phone)
            sendCode()
        }, 1000);
    }, [])

[...]

<FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
                ref={recaptchaVerifier}
                firebaseConfig={firebase.app().options}
                androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
                attemptInvisibleVerification={attemptInvisibleVerification}
            />

{attemptInvisibleVerification && <FirebaseRecaptchaBanner />}
```

Answer (score 1):

your verifyPhoneNumber parameter is incomplete. You dont have the codeSent parameter that generates the verificationId for you..here is the complete parameter of the verifyPhoneNumber method.

```js
Future<void> registerWithPhone(){
await _authInstance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        ///it execute this block if successful
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException exception) async {
        ///it execute this block it verification failed. So its good practice to execute alert dialog here
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        /// verificationId is generated here. So you need to catch it and save to a variable like this:
        _verificationID = verificationId;
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) async {
        _verificationID = verificationId;
      },
      // timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
    );
}
```